# outputting data from multiple methods in java

Tags: arrays, string, object, methods

currently the program is listing the planets in a solar system. each planet entered to the solarsystem has a position counter adding position++

after all the planets are listed I want to SystemPrintln a statement saying, There are this many planets in your solar system. Should I not be able to just return position; for this?

At this point the result is in a toString so to add this final line stating the number of planets how would I do this?

1. Could I add a second method "position" to the toString?
2. can I just return position in a system.out.println statement from the drive class?

class Planet:
    package planets;

```
public class Planet  {


    String name;
    int moons;

    public Planet(String name, int moons)
    {
        this.moons = moons;
        this.name = name;               
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The Planet " + name  + " Has " + moons + " Moon(s) \r\n ";
    }

}
```

Class SolarSystem:

```
     package planets;

public class SolarSystem {

    private Planet[]planets;
    private int position = 0;

 public SolarSystem(int size) {


     planets = new Planet[size];
 }

public void add(Planet planet) {
    planets[position] = planet;
    position++;

}

public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
        result += planets[i].toString(); 
    } 
    return result;  
}

}
```

Class Driver:
    package planets;

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Planet mercury  = new Planet ("Mercury", 0);

        Planet venus = new Planet ("Venus", 0);

        Planet earth = new Planet ("Earth", 1);

        Planet mars = new Planet ("Mars", 2);

        Planet jupiter = new Planet ("Jupiter", 67);

        Planet saturn = new Planet ("Saturn", 62);

        Planet uranus = new Planet ("Uranus", 27);

        Planet neptune = new Planet ("Neptune", 14);

        Planet pluto = new Planet ("Pluto", 5);

        SolarSystem solarSystem = new SolarSystem(9);       

        solarSystem.add(mercury);
        solarSystem.add(venus);
        solarSystem.add(earth);
        solarSystem.add(mars);
        solarSystem.add(jupiter);
        solarSystem.add(saturn);
        solarSystem.add(uranus);
        solarSystem.add(neptune);
        solarSystem.add(pluto);



        System.out.println(solarSystem);

    }

}
```

Comment: with `sumPlanets()`, do you want the total number of planets in the array? If so, that's inherent in `planets.length`. Note - your `sumPlanets()` method calls `planet`, which is not defined in your class.

Comment: yes I just want to print the total number of planets.. I would really appreciate it if you could explain this to me.. I am terrible at java

Answer (score 0):

For your class you have to return the position variabel.

```
public int sumPlanets(){
   return position;
}
```

and in your method toString use :

```
public String toString(){
    return Integer.toString(sumPlanets());
}
```

but i recommend only use the position for return the total elements

```
public String toString(){
    return position;
}
```

In your in your code :

```
package planets;

    public class SolarSystem {

        private Planet[]planets;
        private int position = 0;

     public SolarSystem(int size) {


         planets = new Planet[size];
     }

    public void add(Planet planet) {
        planets[position] = planet;
        position++;

    }

    public String toString(){
       return Integer.toString(sumPlanets());
    }

    public int sumPlanets(){
       return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind taking your code and adding it to my code so I can see exactly what your saying... I am really confused on how this methods are all ending up working together and being added to the toString.

Comment: I see what you did but by taking away my current toString you cleared my results which list the current planets that are in the solar system

Comment: you want to show what planets are in your system solar ?

Comment: I am showing the planets in the solar system. how many moons are with each panet. so at the end it prints this.
The Planet Mercury Has 0 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Venus Has 0 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Earth Has 1 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Mars Has 2 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Jupiter Has 67 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Saturn Has 62 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Uranus Has 27 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Neptune Has 14 Moon(s) 
 The Planet Pluto Has 5 Moon(s) 
I need to add at the end... there are 9 planets in your solar system with a method and I need to add the total amount of the moons.

Comment: I understand but you have to copy your code about your Planets.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print out the total number of planets I used the position variable which adds one each time a planets object is made.

```
position++
```

so to print this I added

```
System.out.println("You Have " + position + " Planets In Your Solar System");
```

Directly after the loop so It would be printed out one time with the total amount.

The full class ended up like this.

```
package planets;

public class SolarSystem {

    private Planet[]planets;
    private int position = 0;

 public SolarSystem(int size) {


     planets = new Planet[size];
 }

public void add(Planet planet) {
    planets[position] = planet;
    position++;

}

public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
        result += planets[i].toString(); 

    }
    System.out.println("You Have " + position + " Planets In Your Solar System");

    return result;  

}
}
```